# Extract content between <\p> using xpath for webscraping

Tags: python, xpath, web-scraping, scrapy

I am trying to extract jokes from a website and I need to get the jokes one by one:

```
div class="oneliner" 
     itemscope="" 
     itemtype="http://schema.org/Article">

            <p>My girl always tells me "Life is about the little things", but I  just hate when she talks about her Ex.</p>
```

What I came up with so far using xpath is

```
.xpath('//div[@class="oneliner"]')
```

With this I am able to extract the single items, but now I want to loop over all occurences and extract the text (everything between \p ). For this I tried

```
for joke in jokes:

     item['joke'] = joke.xpath('//p/text()').extract()
```

But this gives me all jokes from that page at once instead of going through one by one. Could anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply iterate through joke nodes and yield an item with every iteration:

```
def parse(self, response):
    jokes = response.xpath('//div[@class="oneliner"]')
    for joke in jokes:
        item = dict()
        item['joke'] = joke.xpath('.//p/text()').extract()
        yield item
```

Comment: This is what I tried, but it extracts all the jokes from all "oneliner" classes at once (so in every joke in jokes loop I get a list of all jokes instead of one after the other)

Comment: Uh great  './/p/text()' instead of '//p/text()' gave the desired result. Would you mind commenting on the effect of the dot?

Comment: @OliverEbrle oh I'm sorry, your xpath was faulty here. You need to use `.` before `.//` when you want to localise the xpath to any other node than the root. In other words: `//` selects everything from documents root, while `.//` selects everything from the current node. I've made an edit